# Converting a string-like object into a string in python

Tags: python, string, types, type-conversion

I am using python and XMLBuilder, a module I downloaded off the internet (pypi). It returns an object, that works like a string (I can do print(x)) but when I use file.write(x) it crashes and throws an error in the XMLBuilder module.

I am just wondering how I can convert the object it returns into a string?

I have confirmed that I am writing to the file correctly.

I have already tried for example x = y although, as I thought, it just creates a pointer, and also `x=x+" "` put I still get an error. It also returns an string like object with "\n".

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `file.write(str(x))`

Comment: Maybe the file.write() function do not call the overloaded __str__ function of the object. Did you try file.write(str(x)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.write(str(x))
```

will likely work for you.

Background information: Most types have a function [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) or [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (or both) defined. If you pass an object of such a type to `print`, it'll recognize that you did not pass a `str` and try to call one of these functions in order to convert the object to a string.

However, not all functions are as smart as `print` and will fail if you pass them something that is not a string. Also string concatenation does not work with mixed types. To work with these functions you'll have to convert the non-string-type objects manually, by wrapping them with `str()`. So for example:

```
x = str(x)+" "
```

This will create a new string and assign it to the variable `x`, which held the object before (you lose that object now!).

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for, and nicely explained too.

Answer (score 1):

The Library has `__str__` defined:

```
def __str__(self):
    return tostring(~self, self.__document()['encoding'])
```

So you just need to use `str(x)`:

```
file.write(str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, but `print` automatically calls `str` on all of it's arguments ...  So if you want the same output as `print` to be put into your file, then `myfile.write(str(whatever))` will put the same text in `myfile` that `print (x)` would have put into the file (minus a trailing newline that print puts in there).

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
print myObject
```

The `__repr__` method is actually called.

So for example you could do: `x += myXMLObject.__repr__()` if you want to append the string representation of that object to your `x` variable.

Comment: `print` calls `__repr__` only when `__str__` is not found.